# Apply logical operator on a list in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have to apply the logical operator `or` on a list of conditions in the `where` function in pyspark. As in pyspark the operators for `or` is `|`, it is not able to use the `any()` function from Python. Has anybody a suggestion how to solve this?

Below a simple example:

```
# List of conditions
spark_conditions = [cond1, cond2, ..., cond100]

# Apply somehow the '|' operator on `spark_conditions`
# spark_conditions would look like -> [cond1 | cond2 | .... | cond100]

df.select(columns).where(spark_conditions)
```

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is actually a pandas question, as `spark.sql.DataFrame` seems at least to behave like a pandas DataFrame.  But I don't know spark.  In any case, your 'spark conditions' are actually (I think)  boolean series.  I'm sure there is some way properly to sum boolean series in pandas, but you can *also* just reduce it like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from funtools import reduce

df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,2,1,4], columns=["num"])
filter1 = df["num"] > 3
filter2 = df["num"] == 2
filter3 = df["num"] == 1
filters = (filter1, filter2, filter3)
filter = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, filters)
df.filter(filter) # note .where is an alias for .filter
```

This works like this:  `reduce()` takes the first two things in filters and runs `lambda x, y: x | y` on them.  Then it takes the output of *that*, and passes it as `x` to `lambda x, y: x | y`, taking the *third* entry in `filters` and passing it as `y`.  It keeps going until it hasn't got anything left to to take.

So the net effect is to apply a function cumulatively along an iterable.  In this case the function just returns `|` of its inputs, so it does exactly what you would do manually, but like this:

```py
(filter1 | filter2) | filter3
```

I suspect there's a more pandasy or sparky way of doing that, but reduce is *sometimes* worth having.  [Guido doesn't like it though](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).

Comment: ...works with spark conditions aswell!

Comment: yes, the `reduce(fn, iterable)` pattern will work with anything: you just apply `fn` accross the iterable.  I'll update the answer to explain how it works.  I thought spark.sql.DataFrame was a pandas DataFrame which spark had extended (hence claiming it's a pandas question) but maybe they just have a similar interface.  I'll make the answer less dogmatic.

Answer (score 1):

[2e0byo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15452601/2e0byo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69361681/9057615) is pretty much correct. I am adding another way how this can be done in pyspark.

If our conditions are strings of SQL conditional expressions (like col_1 == 'ABC101'), we can combine all those strings and feed that combined string as a condition to `where()` (or `filter()`).

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "a"),
                            (2, "b"),
                            (3, "c"),
                            (4, "d"),
                            (5, "e"),
                            (6, "f"),
                            (7, "g")], schema="id int, name string")
condition1 = "id == 1"
condition2 = "id == 4"
condition3 = "id == 6"
conditions = [condition1, condition2, condition3]
combined_or_condition = " or ".join(conditions)     # Combine the conditions: condition1 or condition2 or condition3
df.where(combined_or_condition).show()
```

`" or ".join(conditions)` creates a string by joining all the strings present in `conditions` using `or` as the delimiter/joiner/combiner. Here, `combined_or_condition` becomes `id == 1 or id == 4 or id == 6`.